# Uber Rush API Sandbox

Tags: uber-api

Trying to test Uber Rush API (from localhost and from linux server).

Calling Token works - I get the token
trying to implement sanbox example:

```
curl -X "PUT /v1/sandbox/deliveries/{delivery_id}" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH TOKEN>" \
  -d "{\"status\":\"en_route_to_pickup\"}"
```

with url https://sandbox-api.uber.com/

and I tried the same request with file_get_contents (in PHP)

So, I always get error "405 Method Not Allowed"

```
{"message":"Method not supported for this endpoint.","code":"method_not_allowed"}
```

What I need to do to get access to method from this sandbox example https://developer.uber.com/docs/rush/sandbox?

Corrent syntax

```
curl -X "PUT" -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"status\":\"en_route_to_pickup\"}" https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/deliveries/DELIVERY_ID
```

Comment: What's the exact call to file_get_contents that you're making?

Comment: `$url = 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/deliveries/ID_HERE';

    $headers = array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.TOKEN_HERE);

    $options = array(
        'https' => array(
        'header'=> $headers ,
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated to reflect both issues in your question...

You have a mismatch in your requests and an incorrect syntax for curl.

First off your CURL request is incorrectly specified.  It should be:

```
curl -X "PUT" -H "Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH TOKEN>" -d "{\"status\":\"en_route_to_pickup\"}" https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/deliveries/{delivery_id}
```

In addition, your curl command is trying to issue a PUT request to the [uber sandbox PUT API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sandbox).  However, your PHP code is not setting the context correctly and so is probably issuing a GET request.  I suspect that the server is therefore rejecting the request as a GET as not allowed to do this sort of operation.

To fix it, see [Bad request using file_get_contents for PUT request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014016/bad-request-using-file-get-contents-for-put-request-in-php).  This should give you an example of how to pass in the necessary context to issue a PUT request using `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: To be clean, I've used all possible opitions to make this request work. This one with method PUT too. $url = 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/deliveries/ID_HERE';

    $headers = array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.TOKEN_HERE);

    $options = array(
        'https' => array(
        'header'=> $headers ,
        'method'  => 'PUT',
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

Comment: I do not worry about php code, I worry about why I get method not allowed on curl command. I get this code here [https://developer.uber.com/docs/rush/sandbox](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rush/sandbox)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов If your problem is the curl request, that's just because it is syntactically incorrect.  See my edited answer...

Comment: Thank you @Peter Prittain, worked like "curl -X "PUT" -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"status\":\"en_route_to_pickup\"}" https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/deliveries/123"

Comment: Great!  As a final step, you might want to tell Uber support that their docs are wrong and/or upvote this answer as helpful...

Comment: Prittain I've tried to vote up, but I have no enought reputation for that. Just marked as answered